# ReferencerError: Define is not defined - Browserify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I'm developing a site on React, and I'm trying to generate the `bundle` with `browserify` throuhg `gulp`

This is my `gulpfile`:

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var babel = require('babelify');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var util = require("gulp-util");
var log = util.log;
var path = require('path');

function compile(watch) {
    var bundler = watchify(browserify('./app.js', { debug: true }));

    function rebundle() {
        bundler.bundle()
            .on('error', function(err) { console.error(err); this.emit('end'); })
            .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
    }

    if (watch) {
        bundler.on('update', function() {
            console.log('-> bundling...');
            rebundle();
        });
    }

    rebundle();
}

function watch() {
    return compile(true);
}

gulp.task('build', function() { return compile(); });
gulp.task('watch', ['sass:watch'], function() { return watch(); });

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

It correclty runs the build, and generates the `bundle`. But after that, when I import to the site I get the error:

> ReferenceError: define is not defined

I guess `browserify`, or the `bundle` generated is expecting some other package that has the define? What I'm missing?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-happy-async": "0.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
    "rest": "^1.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-core": "^5.8.25",
    "babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
    "babelify": "^6.1.2",
    "browserify": "^13.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.6.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.21",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.4",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but I was compiling typescript with 'module: amd' compiler option which shouldn't have been enabled.

Comment: you should be able to figure out where is that error triggered and try to debug from there. source maps will show you the line and the file that triggers that error.